# How to calculate processor throughput boundary in CSAPP?

Tags: optimization, ar.hardware-architecture

In Chapter 5.7 of CSAPP, author list out the throughput boundary of Intel Core i7 Haswell while executing the operation Integer addition and multiplication, floating points addition and multiplication. Here is the function units list.[image]
The author also pointed out the equation was throughput boundary = Capacity/Issue. Here is the data.[image]

I wonder how did the result equals to 0.5.[image]
Because if the capacity is 2 and the issue is 1, it should be 2 right?

Comment: This question is not theoretical computer science, and it is off-topic on this site. Topic-wise, it seems it might belong to electrical engineering https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ , but I do not really know if this is a good question for that site.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You confused the definition of maximum throughput and throughput bound:

- Maximum throughput =  Capacity/Issue time
- Throughput bound "gives a minimum bound for the CPE based on the maximum rate at which the functional units can produce results" (quoted from CSAPP). So throughput bound is the theoretical minimum CPE(Cycles per Element) caused by maximum throughput. Throughput bound = 1/maximum throughput.